# Change the popup element when matching a URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an "activate" button on my popup, which should be disabled by default, and  should become clickable when viewing YouTube.com video page  (i.e url matches "/watch/?v=")

How this should be done? With `background.js` or with `popup.js`? I'm confused.

Comment: [Get the tab URL](/a/17826527) and change the element's style accordingly. In popup.js.

Comment: Thank you. works

Answer (score 1):

This is my final solution (in popup.js as suggested here)

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var tabURL = tab.url;
    if (tabURL.includes('youtube.com/watch?v')) {
        jQuery('#activation-button').removeClass('unavailable');
    }
});
```

Comment: I could find this useful.  I was running it from the console, just testing but in any event, I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you match urls in the manifest, therefore it would only work on youtube pages?  I don't see why you couldn't do this using [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).  In any event, if you must choose between the background and popup, I would say popup.js because you would want it to check initially of clicking popup.html.

So you have popup.html, and then it has a button called "Activate".  Just make another file called activate.js.  In activate.js

```
function activate(){
    var test =  window.location.href
    if (test.includes('watch?v')){
    console.log('Yes')}
    }
activate()
```

Include activate.js in your popup.html.

Comment: I want the pop-up to be available on all pages, just part of it, the button to  be available on the video pages

Comment: Thank, helped me to find the final solution,  when I tried that. window.location.href has return the URL of the extension and not the tab URL. I used @wOxxOm suggestion to find the tab URL.